# Why totals.hit is larger than 1 while totals.timeOnSite is null in bigquery?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-analytics-api

I want to calculate the average time spent originating from email promotion. I have found a lot of sessions starting from the email have multiple hits `totals.hits > 1` while the `totals.timeOnSite` is null. I am wondering if I have some misunderstanding here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked if that hits are non-interaction? If an event is non-interaction type, it will not be considered in the calculation of the time on site and other metrics like bounce rate.

Comment: Good call Michele! Thank you!

Comment: And if these are interaction events?

Comment: @Avantika Banerjee: show some screenshot of the situation, pls